# Unicode Nirmala UI Devenagari font issue while displaying in Android app developed in Delphi 10.4

Tags: android, delphi, unicode, rendering, firemonkey

I am developing an app in Delphi 10.4 for Android mobile. I am using Unicode Devnagari font (Nepali) in the app, which displays correctly while running on Windows. But it displays incorrectly when deployed on Android mobile as shown below.

I want the text like भासा in `TEdit`, which is shown correctly in design time and runtime on desktop but when I deploy it on Android Samsung m 52 it displays like भ ास ा

It happens in `TEdit`, `TLabel`, `TMemo` controls.

When I copy the wrong text भ ास ा from my app to messenger, SMS it shows correctly. If I copy the correct one in to my app in `TEdit` it converts into भ ास ा

I have deployed appropriate font in the deployment as well but it did not solve the problem. I see this issue on the mobile device only in my application.

How to display भासा instead of भ ास ा on Android device

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue in FireMonkey reported as: Incorrect rendering of RTL text on mobile platforms
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27872

While the report is for right to left languages, it seems that cause of the issue is that on some platforms, like Android and iOS, FireMonkey draws text character by character which breaks the text that requires ligatures for proper display.

For some controls, like `TEdit` solution is to set `ControlType` property to `Platform`, instead of using default `Styled` option. Unfortunately, that solution does not work for all FMX controls.

Since platform controls know how to paint text with ligatures correctly, one of possible solutions for other controls would be to implement wrappers for native platform controls on each platform. FireMonkey code for `TEdit` offers insight on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your note. Can you please tell me the workaround solution if possible? This is happening while showing SQLite data in the TListView

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I changed the Tedit  ControlType property to Platform and it worked but it did not work for TMemo and TListView.  Can you please suggest me a workaround solution if possible? This is happening while showing SQLite data displayed in the TListView. I am using RAD Studio 10.4.1

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no simple workaround for TMemo or  TListView. It would require wrapping Android native control `TextView` for presenting text On Android TEdit control platform wrapper wraps EditText class which is descendant on TextView. You can look into that implementation, and make similar wrapper just for TextView.  For TMemo, you can extend TEdit but modify it to be multiline control - EditText supports both. I cannot give you out of the box solution because it is not just few lines of code and I don't have it already implemented.

Comment: The problem is solved by using Skia4Delphi. Enable Skia in he project and all Asian font rendering issues are gone. Skia4Delphi is a great add-on for Delphi Developers. Thank you once again for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: @suren If you have solved your issue by using Skia you may want to add an answer saying that so that people with the same issue can more easily find the solution.